# Why does BatchableContext.getChildJobId() return null inside Database.Batchable.execute()?

Tags: batch

Per [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm?search_text=getJobId), `BatchableContext.getChildJobId()` should return the id of the current batch chunk; when running in `Database.Batchable.execute()` I would expect that to always be populated.  I'm using it in some batch job logging code, but I'm seeing logs generated with a null value for the child log Id.  I added some additional debug statements to a unit test to report the childJobId, and I'm seeing it there as well.  What would cause this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'd be null if no chunks were generated (e.g. the number of records fits in a single chunk). I'm not sure what that means *exactly*, but I suspect this means that anything of less than about 20 executions probably won't have children.